# compile error with boost hana define struct

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-hana

I am starting with boost hana, and I am currently getting this compile problem while writing a basic program:

```
#include <boost/hana/define_struct.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;
struct Foo
{
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Foo,
     (int, var1_),
     (double, var2),
     );
};
```

I am using latest gcc compiler (6.1) and the compiler error that I get is

```
boost/hana/detail/struct_macros.hpp:2462:103: error:
‘BOOST_HANA_PP_DROP_BACK’ does not name a type
```

This is weird because when I looked at the headers, `boost/hana/detail/preprocessor.hpp` (a file included by the above `struct_macros.hpp`) does include this macro definition.

EDIT: Macros are horrible. :( Take a look at first answer.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
struct Foo
{
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Foo,
     (int, var1_),
     (double, var2) // no comma
     );
};
```